# What is the meaning of 'in my honor'?

Tags: meaning

I attended a farewell dinner in my honor.

Can you tell me what is the meaning of 'in my honor'?

Comment: It was to *honor* you.  What does the word mean?

Answer (score 2):

According to Oxford dictionary, [Honor (*British: Honour*)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/honour) means

> As a celebration of or expression of respect for.
>
> *‘a dinner given in honour of Nevinson’*

So, "In my honor" means the farewell was *arranged for you*, to bid you farewell.

Comment: This would be better with references.

Comment: @Davo Yes, added.